# Update method in mutable HashSet class in Scala

Tags: java, scala, collections, hashset

HashSet class in Scala's mutable collections supports update method.

However, name `update` seems counter-intuitive(to me atleast). From the documentation [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.6.0/scala/collection/mutable/Set.html#update%28A%2CBoolean%29) it says

> This method allows one to add or remove an element elem from this set depending on the value of parameter included. Typically, one would use the following syntax:
>   set(elem) = true

I tried using `update` on scala console. When I called `update(elem, true)` instead of updating elem with new version, it just did nothing when the element was present.

When update(elem, false), it removed the elem.

My question is what is the purpose of `update` method as it is not `updating` anything

Answer (score 3):

I think the update is intended on the set and not on the elements in the set (it doesn't make sense to "update" an element, it only makes sense for collections which have a key-value relationship), and in fact if you look at the source code, this method does update the set:

```
def update(elem: A, included: Boolean) {
  if (included) this += elem else this -= elem
}
```

So basically you can use the `included` variable to tell wether to add or remove an element, in your case adding twice the same element doesn't give you any update because a set doesn't allow duplicates.

Why one would use `update` instead of `add` or `remove` it's outside my comprehension.

Comment: So is it just an alias for `put` and `remove` combined into one, differentiated with `included` argument?

Comment: Yes, there's a small difference in the return type, `update` returns `Unit`, `add` and `remove` return booleans, for example if you add twice the same element, the first call will return true, the second false.

Comment: "Why one would use `update` instead of `add` or `remove` it's outside my comprehension." – Because `foo(bar) = baz` is syntactic sugar for `foo.update(bar, baz)` and `mySet(myElem) = true` or `mySet(myElem) = false` kinda-sorta makes sense for adding/removing elements, because it is symmetric with `apply`: `mySet(myElem) // => true` means `myElem` is a member of `mySet`, `mySet(myElem) // => false` means `myElem` is *not* a member of `mySet`.